# Show whether who disconnected a user from voice channel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So basically I have a question now. And I made a logs for showing people who join/leave/move between the voice channel and now I want to expand the function of it. So I've decided to show if somebody disconnect a user from a channel. But I have a problem while fetching audit logs into this. If I disconnected somebody once and someone leave on its own after, it still shows up that I disconnected the users. So I am thinking is it possible to fix this issue by fetching a specific time of audit log but I don't know how to do this. Here is a part of code which shows the disconnect and leave part.

```
 else if (newUserChannel === null) {

        // User leaves a voice channel

        const fetchedLogs = await (oldMember, newMember).guild.fetchAuditLogs({
            limit: 1,
            type: 'MEMBER_DISCONNECT',
        });

        const disconnectLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();
        // console.log(disconnectLog)
        const { executor } = disconnectLog;

        const Disconnected = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#555555')
            .setAuthor(`${executor.username}#${executor.discriminator}`, executor.displayAvatarURL())
            .setDescription(`<@${executor.id}> **has disconnected user** <@${oldMember.id}>`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(F1, F2)

        const VCLeave = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#55FFFF')
            .setAuthor(`${oldMember.member.user.tag}`, oldMember.member.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true }))
            .setDescription(`<@${oldMember.id}> **has left voice channel \`${oldUserChannel.name}\`**`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter(F1, F2)

        LogsChannel.send(Disconnected);
        LogsChannel.send(VCLeave);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the entry's time is a good idea to fix this issue, in my opinion.

[`disconnectLog`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildAuditLogsEntry) has a property called [`createdAt`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildAuditLogsEntry?scrollTo=createdAt) (Date) and [`createdTimestamp`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildAuditLogsEntry?scrollTo=createdTimestamp) (Number).

This is how you get the entry's time and compare it later to the current date.

---

```js
const Diff = Math.abs((new Date().getTime() - disconnectLog.createdAt.getTime()) / 1000);

if (Diff <= 5) {console.log("The entry was created less than 5 seconds ago, so the user was disconnected by an admin.")};
```

Comment: Well I have made disconnectLog.createdTimestamp to compare with the current timestamp when it runs that part of the code. But if on the audit-log, no more things update so there is only a user disconnecting a member, and it will not able to compare since it logs XXX#0000 disconnected (Ex:3) members instead of creating new logs every single time when someone disconnect a user from voice channel. Do you have any clue to solve it?

Comment: I've updated my code. I'm comparing the time between the 2 dates in seconds. If more than 5 seconds passed since the last entry, the user left the channel, otherwise, an admin disconnected them. (5 is a number I came with, you can increase it or decrease it, depending on how fast Discord API is)

Comment: Well I thought using audit log and comparing the events time is working but unfortunately it isn’t. Since discord audit log logs the member disconnect events as count. Like if I disconnected 2 users from voice channel. It is showing (My Tag) disconnected 2 members instead of creating a new log. Do you have clue on that?

Comment: I think we should move this conversation to the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225891/room-for-jakye-and-bobosky).