# Discord.js v13 send a message when kicked from the voice channel

Tags: discord.js, disconnect

I'm trying to make a code that the bot send a message when is disconnected from voice channel for someone, but the bot is also sending this message when i use the quit command, there's a way to execute that code only when the bot gets kicked from voice channel by someone, and not by command?
My code:

client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldState, newState) => {

```
        if(oldState.channelId === newState.chanelId) return console.log('Mute/Deafen Update');
      
        if(!oldState.channelId && newState.channelId) return console.log('Connection Update');
      
        if(oldState.channelId && !newState.channelId){
          console.log('Disconnection Update');
          if(newState.id === client.user.id) return (
              await queue.destroy(),
              interaction.channel.send("I've kicked from the voice channel")
            )

            
        }
        
    });
```

Comment: Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65169777/19220341), you can easily solve your problem using it.

Comment: When i tried, it said that disconnectLog is not defined, what i can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Define it like that :

```
const fetchedLogs = await (oldMember, newMember).guild.fetchAuditLogs({
    limit: 1,
    type: 'MEMBER_DISCONNECT',
});

const disconnectLog = fetchedLogs.entries.first();
// console.log(disconnectLog)
const { executor } = disconnectLog;
```

Be careful, it will get an executor also when nobody kick the bot, so you have to compare the log's timestamp with the leave's timestamp.

Comment: I have one doubt about it, that command only works if in the audit log show that i've disconnected only 1 user, but if i disconnect many users in a row, the audit log sums the disconnected users instead of creating another log, so the command doesn't work in that circunstances, is there a way to solve this?

Comment: The `executor` still the same, you just have to check if there's the bot in the list of disconnected user and if the timestamps are almost the same.

Comment: Like this for example? if (Diff <= 5 && disconnectLog === client.user.id) {console.log("The entry was created less than 5 seconds ago, so the user was disconnected by an admin.")};

Comment: Nop, `disconnectLog` is the user who kicked your bot

Comment: How do i check if the bot was disconnected then? sorry, i'm new with discord.js

Comment: Sorry I do a mistake, `disconnectLog` represents all the data of the log, and `executor` represents the user who kicked. So you can console.log the `disconnectLog` variable to check all values